# Stack divs next to each other

Tags: css

I want to align boxes on a site completely up against each other. I set a `margin-bottom: 1%` and `margin-right: 1%` and then everything should align to the top using `vertical-align: top`.

Here is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/9a2sfk1y/2/

```
margin-right: 1%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

This will look like this:

[image]

However, I want the boxes to go stacked like this:

[image]

How would I go on about that? My original idea was to put them inside a table, but I'm sure you can do this with just CSS. Or am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are there only going to be 2 columns? Or an unknown amount of columns?

Comment: Is this just with CSS hardcoded, etc or are you willing to use jquery? If so, you can use Masonry to make it easier and faster than doing things by yourself. Here's the link: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @Markasoftware Sorry yes, only two columns. I forgot to include that.

Comment: @Nina I could try that. Thanks.

Comment: @Nina Works wonderfully: https://jsfiddle.net/9a2sfk1y/6/ - Thanks for that suggestion, however, it would be nice to have it done with pure CSS.

Comment: @Snorlax You can't really. Not until CSS Grids comes out.

Comment: @TylerH CSS can do it alone, I think

Comment: @Snorlax here's how I would do it with CSS only, no js (mainly because I have a grudge against jQuery): https://jsfiddle.net/9a2sfk1y/5/

Comment: @Markasoftware Try adding text to those divs and see what happens, of varying height, and have the divs able to shrink and grow to fit their content. It's easy to make a layout of boxes. What's hard is making that layout work with dynamic content in it.

Comment: @TylerH ok, that makes sense. However, I still don't think js is needed. Can't flexbox do this pretty easily? And it has support across all major browsers.

Comment: @Markasoftware Yes, flexbox can handle the basics, but there are a lot of users who use browsers that don't support it well. Anyway, this is the kind of thing CSS Grids is designed for. It'll be *the* way to make layouts like this once it's ready for browsers.

Comment: Actually, flex is supported in all modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox